# DI-kafkaMeter send message errr

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I use jmeter DI-kafkaMeter to send message to kafka

Error sending message to kafka topic : java.lang.RuntimeException: Kafka Producer Client not found. Check Variable Name in KafkaProducerSampler.

INFO o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer: [Producer clientId=JMeter-Producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2023-02-24 16:17:12,544 ERROR c.d.j.k.c.KafkaProducerConfig: Error establishing Kafka producer client !!

ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: setEndTime must be called after setStartTime
java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence

Error sending message to kafka topic : java.lang.RuntimeException: Kafka Producer Client not found. Check Variable Name in KafkaProducerSampler.

INFO o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer: [Producer clientId=JMeter-Producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2023-02-24 16:17:12,544 ERROR c.d.j.k.c.KafkaProducerConfig: Error establishing Kafka producer client !!

ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: setEndTime must be called after setStartTime
java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the [Sampler.sample()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/Sampler.html#sample(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.Entry)) function is not implemented properly in the "DI-kafkaMeter" (whatever it is) and there is nothing you can do about it unless you fix the error in the source code, recompile the plugin and put the fixed version to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

In the meantime you can either consider using another plugin, i.e. [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) or just add [Kafka Java client libraries](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/java/current/overview.html) to JMeter's "lib" folder and use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) for sending the message.

Example code can be found i.e. [here](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/java/#build-producer)

Simplified version to use in the JSR223 Sampler:

```
def props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

def producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<>(props);

producer.send(new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord<>("your-topic", "your-key", "your-encrypted-value"));

producer.close();
```

More information: [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing)